# How do I implement nested steps within an individual Material UI Stepper Step (A Step Within A Stepper Step [Child Steps within Parent Steps] )

Tags: material-ui, stepper, formik-material-ui

## I want to use nested Step Components within a Material UI Stepper Component

This is the behavior that I am seeking. I am using Material UI, and Formik within a NextJS context. I am using [the tutorial](https://youtu.be/l3NEC4McW3g) as a reference.

### Wireframes

Below are some wireframes that help illustrate what each the three top-level parent steps, and the third screenshot illustrates that the last parent step (step 3) has three, nested child steps.

#### Parent Step One - *Tell Us About Your Property* NO CHILDREN STEPS

This is the first step in the form. The customer will provide info on the land or standing structure that will have media produced (depending on there choice certain products will not be options they can select).

> **Screenshot 1:** This is the first step in the form

[step one screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnoKL.jpg)

#### Parent Step Two - *Select Your Services* A PORTAL WITH MULTIPLE PRODUCTS AND PACKAGES

This step will actually be a non-linear portal to seeing categorized products. There are four service categories with products and sub-packages. The goal is to be able to pick and select products and add them to the cart.

> **Screenshot 2:** This is the homepage/ portal

[step two screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuG9D.jpg)

#### Parent Step Three - *Provide Some Info* 3 CHILD STEPS

This step will actually be a non-linear portal to seeing categorized products. There are four service categories with products and sub-packages. The goal is to be able to pick and select products and add them to the cart.

> **Screenshot 3:** This is the place we collect info within 3 child "steps"

[step three screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8VR7.jpg)

Here is the rundown on the Material Ui Stepper Component.
https://material-ui.com/components/steppers/

### Dependencies / Environment

1. I forked this repo as a starting point: https://github.com/CharlestonREM/youtube-2020-june-multi-step-form-formik
2. I am using Formik-Material UI: https://github.com/stackworx/formik-material-ui
3. I want to employ the Material UI Stepper Component with nested steps: https://material-ui.com/components/steppers/

Comment: The creator of the tutorial Bruno Antunes responded to comments on the video and gave tips in the reply thread. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3NEC4McW3g&lc=UgznujbWOFE-dexzLSJ4AaABAg

Comment: **new approach** : based on the convo with bruno, i'm gonna try to fork the repo of the video tutorial, and attempt @bmvantunes suggested implementation. the plan is to try to have 7-8 step components in the Stepper parent component, and only display my "big three" steps at the top of the UI.